# Code outside loop executing first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 12 coloured squares, which when a button is clicked, 6 are selected at random and the background colour changed to black.

The squares were all changing colour simultaneously until I added the setTimeout function which has fixed that issue but has caused another one - the code outside the loop is being executed before the loop i.e. calling the Reset function and the alert.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6;i++)
{
setTimeout(function () 
{
  var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];       
  var square = document.getElementById('square' + rand);
  square.style.background="black";
},1000 * i);
}

Reset()
alert("Reset function")
```

I take it that the setTimeout function is somehow causing this - is there a way to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of a timeout?

Comment: Seriously, i don't understand your issue because what you describe is exactly the purpose of a timeout, delaying execution of any code or function

Comment: Yes I understand that ans as I said above it is working correctly in that respect but is causing the code outside the loop to be executed first.  The Reset function isn't meant to be called until after the loop has executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a closure should fix your issue:

```
var length = 6;

for (var i = 0; i < length ; i++)
(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        var square = document.getElementById('square' + rand);
        square.style.background = "black";
        if (i === length - 1) Reset();

    }, 1000 * i);
})(i);


function Reset() {
    alert("Reset function")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say that the error is caused by the missing curly braces around your for loop. Before setTimeout and after the last portion of your loop there should be an { or }

Comment: Thanks but including the missing curly braces hasn't made any difference.